# Easy question on integrals

Tags: integration, inequality

I have some problems understanding this inequality:

$$\int_{x-\varepsilon x}^x \vartheta\left(t\right)dt \leq \vartheta\left(x\right)x\varepsilon$$

where $\vartheta\left(x\right)$ is the Čebyšëv (or Chebyshev, or Tschebyscheff...) theta function.

Can you please give me a formal proof that given a non decreasing function $f$, the inequality
$$\int_{x-\varepsilon x}^x f\left(t\right)dt \leq f\left(x\right)x\varepsilon$$ 
holds?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$ f(t) \leq \max_{t\in [x-x\varepsilon,x]} f(t) = f(x)$$
and conclude

$$\int_{x-\varepsilon x}^{x} f(t)\,dt \leq \int_{x-\varepsilon x}^{x} f(x)\, dt = f(x) [x-(x-\varepsilon x)].$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\varepsilon$ and $x$ are both non-negative, let $g$ be the constant function whose value is $f(x)$ everywhere. Then because $f$ is non-decreasing we have $g(t)\le f(t)$ for $t\le x$. Thus, in particular
$$ \int_{x-\varepsilon x}^x f(t)\,dt \le \int_{x-\varepsilon x}^x g(t)\,dt = \int_{x-\varepsilon x}^x f(x)\,dt = \varepsilon x f(x)$$